# Set custom shape of the Daimajia SliderLayout

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am having problem in setting up the custom shape of SliderLayout. I am using Daimajia Library for this. Can anyone please help.
I am posting the xml below (Shape I required)

```
<!-- Colored rectangle-->
<item android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="-10dp">


    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="335dp"
            android:height="@dimen/dp300" />
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="265dp"
    android:bottom="-50dp"
    android:right="-10dp"
    android:left="-10dp">

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-8">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Comment: what is the custom shape you want? welcome to android development

Comment: @kkarakk. I posted the xml of the desired shape

Answer (score 0):

Daimajia SliderLayout is a custom 3rd party library Slider layout.. and as at now it doesn't even show the "Android:background" attribute in it for you to be able make a custom shape and set that custom shape as its background shape...

So honestly, it will remain as a Rectangle for now and cant be curved and changed to a different shape....
Maybe unless you research and use a totally different slider layout library where you can change its shape

Answer (score 0):

finally after 2 hours dealing with this problem i found the answear.
first you need to add  [     implementation 'com.jcminarro:RoundKornerLayouts:0.4.0'
 ] library which help you curve any layer u want : this is an example :

```
 <com.jcminarro.roundkornerlayout.RoundKornerRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rtl_slider_advertisment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:corner_radius="5dp">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider_advertisment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                />
            <com.jcminarro.roundkornerlayout.RoundKornerRelativeLayout

                android:background="@drawable/gold_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"></com.jcminarro.roundkornerlayout.RoundKornerRelativeLayout>
        </com.jcminarro.roundkornerlayout.RoundKornerRelativeLayout>
```